USB Power delivery: what happens if device requests intermediate of power supply's supported powers?
For example, if you connect Power adapter that supports USB PD 3.0 with PPS, output of 5V, 15V, to a device which requests 9V (and does not support PPS), is it possible that power adapter would give more than 9V (15V)?

If the power supply supports 5..15V in PPS, it makes no sense why it would not support 9V as well in fixed mode. Why would such a device exist? And of course, it is possible that any charger has a glitch and outputs 15V to your 9V device, but you might never encounter that scenario. It is also possible that a meteor or lightning hits you, but you might never encounter that scenario during your lifetime, just to put it into perspective. Devices can amways damage and then destroy other devices when plugging them, electrically or mechanically.

In short, no. If the device and the power adapter don't come to an agreement, then everything stays on 5V. The device won't get 15V unless it asks for 15V. If it can't handle 15V, and 9V isn't available, it can ask for 5V 3A, or it can do nothing.

Assuming proper application and design, that would never happen for the following reasons:

Exceeding intended voltage would bypass any built-in safety mechanisms that would monitor this.

Handshaking between source and device would be bypassed, since the device never responded to the source about what voltage it needs.


There would never be an agreement between what the device needs and what the adapter can deliver.
